# Delete java object

Tags: java, oop, processing

How can I delete an object in java? I have a node which is created once in a function, but the node is still showing on the screen. I am using Processing.

```
void f(){
  Node n = new Node('g');
  n.x = 500;
  n.y = 500;
  n = null;
}
```

And the constructor looks like this:

```
Node(char c){
    this.expression = c;
    registerMethod("draw", this);
    registerMethod("mouseEvent", this);
  }
```

Comment: Are you asking about how to delete data from memory, or how to delete something that was drawn to the screen?

Comment: I am asking how to delete an object from memory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot delete an object in Java. The garbage collector will destroy it once there are no more references to that object. Making your variable null will bring you one step closer to having the object deleted.

Comment: Exactly. `registerMethod(..., this`) probably creates more references to the Node, which is why it is not deleted by the Garbage Collector.